# Geocode Locator - USA_PostalEXT locator for Zip+4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, zip4

I have a list of addresses for which I need to get the ZIP+4. I am trying to geocode following https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014901 which specifies to select the USA_PostalEXT locator to get the ZIP+4 in the output. Does anyone know what the USA_PostalEXT locator is, and how I can get it? Can I get ZIP+4 using the ArcGIS World Geocoding Service? I have ArcMap 10.5, ArcGIS Pro 2.5.1, and can use Python. AGOL credits are not an issue.

Comment: Have you tried the ArcGIS World Geocoding Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer to what or where the USA_PostalExt locator is, but I was able to get the desired results following the workflow in the link and using the ArcGIS World Geocoding Service. The PostalExt attribute field is populated after reverse geocoding.[image]